# Calling multiple URLs in succession using UIApplication.shared.open - only opens first

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, uiapplication

I'm trying to create a wifi tress test by opening multiple URLs in succession in Xcode/Swift for iPad. It seems to open only the first successfully. The "sleep(x)" call makes no difference. Code snippet:

```
func counter()
{
    seconds -= 1
    label.text = String(seconds) + " Seconds"

    if (seconds == 0)
    {

        let url1 = URL(string: "http://www.wix.com")!
        let url2 = URL(string: "http://www.activistpost.com")!
        let url3 = URL(string: "http://www.time.com")!
        let url4 = URL(string: "http://www.steemit.com")!
        let url5 = URL(string: "http://www.youtube.com")!
        let url6 = URL(string: "http://www.cptts.net/61m.jpg")!

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open (url1)
            sleep (5)
            UIApplication.shared.open (url2)
            sleep (5)
            UIApplication.shared.open (url3)
            sleep (5)
            UIApplication.shared.open (url4)
            sleep (5)
            UIApplication.shared.open (url5)
            sleep (5)
            UIApplication.shared.open (url6)

        } else {
           // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
```

Xcode 10.0 Beta 2

Comment: FYI - never "sleep" on the main queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a wifi tress test

Well, that's not how to do it. Also, I wonder whether you really need to do it; the developer tools already allow you to simulate a busy network for testing purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As a wifi tester I'd like to develop my own apps for testing that can be customized (also for self-learning for Xcode dev.). What I posted was only a snippet.

Comment: Wifi tester, uuh? Maybe you instead want to load the websites with NSUrlSession?

Answer (score 0):

As i quote from [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622961-openurl), it appears to be it will only execute the first and the app will quit and it will launch the other app if found.

> The URL you pass to this method can identify a resource in the app
>   that calls the method, or a resource to be handled by another app. If
>   the resource is to be handled another app, invoking this method might
>   cause the calling app to quit so the other can launch.

So eventually ones your app quits then your other calls won't by executed.